# Removing Custom Objects from List in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to remove an element from a list which is stored in NSUserDefaults. The getAll function is implemented below:

```
  func getAllOrders() -> [Order] {

        var orders = [Order]()

        if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.johndoe.SoupChef.Shared") {

            if let ordersData = userDefaults.data(forKey: "Orders") {
                orders = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Order].self, from: ordersData)
            }
        }

        return orders
    }
```

And here is the code for deleting the order.

```
func delete(order :Order) {

        var persistedOrders = getAllOrders()

        persistedOrders.removeAll { persistedOrder in
            persistedOrder.identifier.uuidString == order.identifier.uuidString
        }

    }
```

After deleting the order in the code above when I call getAllOrders I still see all the elements, meaning I don't see the order being deleted.

Comment: Do not edit your question to update it with a solution. Either accept one of the answers if appropriate or post your own answer with the full solution.

Comment: FYI - Do not store your app data in `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't save your changes. Once you've performed the removal you need to turn `persistedOrders` back into JSON and then:

```
userDefaults.set(json, forKey:"Orders")
```

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that since I am removing from the same orders list it would automatically update the saved collection (by reference)

Comment: he need to turn it again to data not json

Comment: Thanks! I updated the original question with the solution.

Comment: I think `synchronize` is now marked as unnecessary by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: you should try catch don't use **try!** as it may cause a crash

Comment: @Sh_Khan I take the responsibility if it crashes while unwrapping. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jsonEncoder and encode the edited array then store it again the user defaults

```
func delete(order :Order) {

    var persistedOrders = getAllOrders()

    persistedOrders.removeAll { persistedOrder in
        persistedOrder.identifier.uuidString == order.identifier.uuidString
    }
    do {

        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(persistedOrders)
        userDefaults.set(data, forKey:"Orders")
    }
    catch {

        print(error)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store correctly your `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey:"Orders")
```

Now, you can remove them using:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Orders")
```